# Variable Cell height fpdf

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

I am creating a pdf generation page with a table on for invoicing, I am using FPDF.

I am trying to change the cell height across each row to vary based on the height of the first column, `$column_item_name`.  The reason for this is so that I can add the item description into the same field as the name and it does not throw out the rest of the rows.

I think I understand the concept.  GetY of cell, set to variable, use variable as height, however I seem to be missing something as have not managed to get it working yet.  Unfortunately I had to roll back so do not have a copy of what I tried.

Current Code for table:

```
//First create each Field Name
//Gray color filling each Field Name box
$pdf->SetFillColor(232,232,232);
//Bold Font for Field Name
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',11);
$pdf->SetY($Y_Fields_Name_position);
$pdf->SetX(10);
$pdf->Cell(100,6,'Description',1,0,'L',1);
$pdf->SetX(110);
$pdf->Cell(30,6,'Rate',1,0,'L',1);
$pdf->SetX(140);
$pdf->Cell(30,6,'Quantity',1,0,'R',1);
$pdf->SetX(170);
$pdf->Cell(30,6,'Price',1,0,'R',1);
$pdf->Ln();


//Now show the 4 columns
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',10);
$pdf->SetY($Y_Table_Position);
$pdf->SetX(10);
$pdf->MultiCell(100,6,$column_item_name,1);
$pdf->SetY($Y_Table_Position);
$pdf->SetX(110);
$pdf->MultiCell(30,6,$column_unit_price,1,'R');
$pdf->SetY($Y_Table_Position);
$pdf->SetX(140);
$pdf->MultiCell(30,6,$column_quantity,1,'R');
$pdf->SetY($Y_Table_Position);
$pdf->SetX(170);
$pdf->MultiCell(30,6,$column_total_price,1,'R');
$pdf->SetX(140);
$pdf->MultiCell(30,6,'Total (exc VAT)',1,'R');
$pdf->SetY($Y_Table_Position + ($number_of_products * 6));
$pdf->SetX(170);
$pdf->MultiCell(30,6,'£ '.$total,1,'R');
$pdf->SetX(140);
$pdf->MultiCell(30,6,$vat3,1,'R');
$pdf->SetY($Y_Table_Position + (($number_of_products + 1) * 6));
$pdf->SetX(170);
$pdf->MultiCell(30,6,'£ '.$vat2,1,'R');
$pdf->SetX(140);
$pdf->MultiCell(30,6,'Total (inc VAT)',1,'R');
$pdf->SetY($Y_Table_Position + (($number_of_products + 2) * 6));
$pdf->SetX(170);
$pdf->MultiCell(30,6,'£ '.$total_inc_vat,1,'R');
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Kind Regards,

n00bstacker

Comment: Is is correct to assume that this is not the full code? As far as I know, with MultiCell, you need to define width & height - like you have already done. Have you looked in to wkhtml2pdf (http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) at all? Making tables can be really easy (or anything else that renders as a webpage).

Comment: Correct that is just the specific table code.  I would like to continue using FPDF as it fits nicely with what I want to achieve - thanks

Answer (score -4, accepted):

There are several scripts on the fpdf.org site that handle variable-height rows in tables. I've collected the main methods in the chapter titled "Tables" in my <strike>free</strike> (no longer free) book at:

http://basepath.com/PDFbook

If you want the first column to establish the row height, rather that the highest column, that's an easy variant of the RowX function that I provide there.

Comment: I moved on to something else - but will come back next time I have this issue.  Thanks

Comment: Book is not free, the first 10 pages are.

Comment: It was free in Jan. 2013.

Comment: Giving a link to a paid ressource is not answering the question.